# Change main shared IP for new accounts in WHM that is DIFFERENT THAN root

Tags: hosting, server, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

If I change "Main Shared Virtual Host IP" to a different IP, it changes ROOT as well. I do NOT want root on the same IP as other shared accounts.

Presently what I have to do is manually change the IP to a different IP with each and every new account because WHM doesn't give an option to choose a shared IP when you create a new account.

However, because this is a pain in the ass, I would like to change the default IP that every new shared account is set up under, that is a DIFFERENT IP than the IP that root is on. Because changing "Main Shared Virtual Host IP" is NOT the solution.

Comment: thanks for all the fast answers, wow, there are infinity aka Zero, I don't know how I will read all your answers wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. change Root reseller accounts IP
2. setup the other resellers to have their own dedicated IP. And do not allow them to use any other IP.

of-course if you restore a backup, will point it to the main IP, and not to the Reseller dedicated IP.

More info on [IP Delegation for reseller](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Manage+Reseller's+IP+Delegation)

Comment: Great! It's true, I had already solved this but this is the correct answer. Thank you for the disclaimer about the restoring backup. I noticed that yesterday, your comment is helpful to understand why. So the answer is to instead just assign new accounts to different reseller on different dedicated IP. That's what I have been doing so this answer is correct.